# l3fp keeping trailing zero in math calc

Tags: siunitx, expl3, l3fp

I would like to keep the trailing zeros when the data, used for internal calculations with `l3fp`, are printed.
For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcnumd}{o m}{\num[#1]{\fp_to_decimal:n{#2}}}
% 
\fp_set:Nn \gpcinque {305.0}
\fp_set:Nn \gptre {272.3}
\ExplSyntaxOff 

\begin{document}

\calcnumd{\gpcinque * sin(pi/2)}\,\si{\kilo\gram}

\calcnumd{\gptre}\,\si{\kilo\gram}

\end{document}
```

will print 272.3 kg and 305 kg instead of 305.0 kg.
Is there a way to avoid the trimming of trailing zeros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FPU does not have a concept of 'significant zeros' in the input: internally everything is converted to a standard form. If you want to force a number of places or significant digits, you'll need to do so at the point of output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\fp_set:Nn \gpcinque {305.0}
\fp_set:Nn \gptre {272.3}
\ExplSyntaxOff 

\begin{document}

\SI{\fpeval{\gpcinque * sin(pi/2)}}{\kilo\gram}

\SI[round-mode = places, round-precision = 1, round-integer-to-decimal]
  {\fpeval{\gpcinque * sin(pi/2)}}{\kilo\gram}

\SI[round-mode = figures, round-precision = 4, round-integer-to-decimal]
  {\fpeval{\gpcinque * sin(pi/2)}}{\kilo\gram}

\end{document}
```

You can set up the rounding approach in the preamble if it is general.

(I've used `\SI` and the fact that we can do expandable calculations here.)